# Use identities to find the exact values at α for the remaining five trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

How should one go about solving this problem?

> Use identities to find the exact values at $\alpha$ for the remaining five
>   trigonometric functions.
>
> $\cos\alpha = -\sqrt{2}/4$ and $\alpha$ is in quadrant III.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\sin\alpha$, use the Trigonometry Fundamental Theorem,
$$\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1,$$
to obtain $\sin\alpha=\pm\sqrt{14}/4.$
Because $\alpha$ is in QIII, its sine must be negative.

For the other four, use $\tan\alpha=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha},$ $\sec\alpha=\frac{1}{\cos\alpha},$ $\csc\alpha=\frac{1}{\sin\alpha},$ $\cot\alpha=\frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}.$

Answer (score 2):

Outline:

In QIII, both sine and cosine are negative.

Use the Pythagorean identity: $\sin^2 \alpha+\cos^2 \alpha = 1$ to find the value of $\sin\alpha$.

Then use quotient and/or reciprocal identities to find the other trig values of $\alpha$.